# Can't mount sd card from micro-python repl through serialport

Tags: python, node.js, read-eval-print-loop, micropython

### What am I trying to do?

Trying to mount the sd card by sending python code through the serialport that is executed on my devices micro-python repl.

### What's my problem?

When I send information through the serialport the code is executed on the device's micro-python repl.
I am trying to execute the following code on my device's repl

```
port.write("os.mount(machine.SDCard(),'/sd')\r\n")
```

However I am met with this error

```
E (1066260) sdmmc_sd: sdmmc_init_sd_scr: send_scr (1) returned 0x109
```

I know that mounting the sd card from the repl is possible because I am able to mount the sd card when I execute that code without sending it through serialport.

Just confused as to why I am met with that error when I try to execute the code from the computer(serial) whereas otherwise no errors are met.

Resorting to stack as I cannot find any solutions to my problem.

Comment: what board are you using?

Comment: Custom board with FTDI chip